# C# version of Array.Unshift() from UnityScript?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I'm trying to write a simple chat box, and I found a really simple piece of code for it on the unity forums, but its in UnityScript (similar to JavaScript).

I tried to convert the code to C# and I've had some success, but the problem is that the code uses `Array.Unshift()`, which prepends an item to an array.  I'm trying to find some simple way of doing this in C#, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

What is the C# equivalent of [`Array.Unshift`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Array.Unshift.html)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per my understanding .Unshift method adds items to the start of array and return new length of array.

You can use `List<T>` collection in C#. To add items at first position of (prepond) to list use following way.

```
List<T>.Insert(0, item); // this will insert item at first position
```

Also you can convert this list to array using `.ToArray()` method of list.

Answer (score 1):

It's tricky with C# arrays. You need to make a new array and copy all elements from the old one, plus the extra element to insert. I suggest using `List<T>` instead, or maybe rethink the algorithm so it doesn't need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you import `System.Linq` it also adds `.Prepend(T obj)` to `IEnumerable<T>` which includes arrays.

```cs
using System.Linq;

//...
int[] example = new int[]{1,2,3};
int[] updated = example.Prepend(0);//{0,1,2,3}
//..
```